# mysql Consecutive Column

Tags: mysql

A table has a values as below,  same number can be repeated in any order. 100,102,101 are repeated value, for these value i need to generate a same number only if they are consecutive values.

```
100
101
102
100
100
103
104
102
102
105
106
101
101
```

Out put Should be

```
100    1
101    2
102    3
100    4
100    4
103    5
104    6
102    7
102    7
105    8
106    9
101    10
101    10
```

Please help for the query

Comment: The second column is one problem getting them to come out in that order without some value to order them on, e.g. DateAdded and auto inc field etc, is a much bigger one.

Comment: Consecutive is a relative term in SQL.  Records might exist in a table in a certain order when viewed in some some sort of tool or result set output, but that does not guarantee that when you do a SELECT... that they will be returned in a specific order unless a sort is specified in the query.  Is there some sort of autoincrement column that you are not mentioning here that actually reflects a true "order" of these items? So if this is some sort of homework assignment, I would call BS on it, and indicate that there is no true mechanism in this table to specify order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your query:

```
SET @t1=0;
SET @tp=-1;

select   
  @t1 := @t1 + (case when @tp=n then 0 else 1 end) as c, 
  n,
  @tp := n
from nums
order by n;
```

Check it at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b136e/9/2

**Explanation**

Do you need two variables. First one is the counter. Seccond var is to remember previus value.
For each row you show counter. You increment counter when previus value is not equal than row value.

**Testing:**

```
create table nums( n int );
insert into nums values (100), (101), (101), (102);
```

Results:

```
| C |   N | @TP := N |
----------------------
| 1 | 100 |      100 |
| 2 | 101 |      101 |
| 2 | 101 |      101 |
| 3 | 102 |      102 |
```